# Custom method on click ClearButton in QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Is it possible to run a custom method on clicking the ClearButton in a QLineEdit?

For instance i have a ClearButton inside a QCombobox and i want to set a default-index on clicking the ClearButton in this ComboBox.

I have already tried to subclass the 'clear()' slot of the QLineEdit, but without success.

Comment: Unset the clear button and use [QLineEdit.addAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#addAction), instead.

Comment: And how can i use the added Action on clicking the clear button. I want the clear button enabled!

Comment: Just create your own clear button using the action (i.e. like you would with a menu-item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[qtawesome](https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtawesome)

[image]
   [image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout)
import qtawesome as qt


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.flag = 0
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self._on_line_edit_text_changed)
        self.clear_icon = qt.icon('mdi.delete-circle-outline', color='gray', color_active='black')
        self.clear_action = None
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def _on_line_edit_text_changed(self):
        if self.line_edit and self.line_edit.text():
            if not self.clear_action:
                self.clear_action = self.line_edit.addAction(self.clear_icon, QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
                self.clear_action.triggered.connect(self._on_clear_clicked)
        elif self.clear_action and self.line_edit and not self.line_edit.text():
            self.line_edit.removeAction(self.clear_action)
            self.clear_action = None

    def _on_clear_clicked(self):
        self.line_edit.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it looks good. I will try later.